# Is it possible to replicate the standard iOS status bar on an external display?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an iOS application that displays the bulk of its data on an external display (either via Airplay or physical cable connection).  Is it possible to display the device's status bar on the external display?  Here's how I'm initializing the external display:

```
func checkForExistingScreenAndInitializeIfPresent() -> UIViewController? {
    if UIScreen.screens.count > 1 {
        if let secondScreen = UIScreen.screens.last {
            return initializeSecondScreen(with: secondScreen)
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func initializeSecondScreen(with secondScreen: UIScreen) -> UIViewController? {
    let screenBounds = secondScreen.bounds
    secondWindow = UIWindow(frame: screenBounds)
    secondWindow?.screen = secondScreen
    secondWindow?.isHidden = false
    secondWindow?.rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homeViewController")
    return secondWindow?.rootViewController
}
```

I have the following code in my HomeViewController.

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return false
}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .default
}
```

The status bar shows up fine in the iOS application for the HomeViewController, but never shows when the HomeViewController is presented on the external display.

Comment: Did you try to set the preferredStatusBarStyle to anything other than **.default**? Maybe to **.light**

Comment: In theory with private apis you can move the original if you are interested... but it will disappear from the main screen of course.

Comment: @Dido I did try .light.  Thanks for the idea though!

Comment: @GiuseppeLanza That's an interesting idea.  Any suggestions on which private APIs to use?

Comment: UIWindow *statusBarWindow = (UIWindow *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] valueForKey:@"statusBarWindow"];

Your app will not be approved toh.

Comment: Hey, @JustinDomnitz, another option I could suggest? Did you try setting the preferStatusBarHidden variable to true in any other place besides the code?

Comment: @GiuseppeLanza This is a corporate app, not going to the App Store so your suggestion worked for me.  Can you post your comment as an answer so I can award you the bounty?

Comment: That is going to sound like an awful hack, but maybe get a snapshot of entire screen, crop it and display it as UIImage?

Comment: @JustinDomnitz I don't think you can move the status bar to the new screen, but you can get all of the data for the status bar (battery percentage, connections, time, etc). Maybe you could create something similar and fix it to the top of that view. Just a thought...